# Javascript - Splicing strings from certain character to next character

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring, splice

Hopefully a basic question, as I'm a bit lost where to begin.

Pretend we have this string in JS:

var foo = **"Yes, today #hello #vcc #toomanyhashtags #test we went to the park and danced"**

How would I go about dynamically finding the character "#" and removing everything after until it hits a space *(or in the instance of **#test**, until the string ends)*?

ie. So the above string would read:

var foo = **"Yes, today we went to the park and danced "**

I had the concept to loop through the entire strings' characters and `if` the character === "#", delete characters until the current loop's item === " ". Is there a shorter way to do this?

### Preliminary Concept:

```
var foo = "Hello, this is my test #test #hello";
var stripHashtags = function(x) {
    for (i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] !== "#") {
            console.log(x[i]);
        }
    }
};
stripHashtags(foo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it with a [simple regex string](http://jsfiddle.net/LhKGx/)

```
foo.replace(/#[^ ]*/g, ""))
```

Comment: I think this answer works best. Any resources you would recommend for learning regex expressions?

Comment: The regex is doing "Find a # characters and everything that is not a space zero or multiple times after and do it globally". SO it scans until it finds a space, the stops. Since there is a g option, it does it globally, so it leaves the spaces. You could delete those too simply by adding one space. As for resources, [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) is good, but try to experiment as you read.

Answer (score 1):

foo.substr(0,foo.indexOf("#")). This can get you the required output i suppose if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, totally helpful. What if it was more like...

"Yes, today #hello #vcc #toomanyhashtags #test we went to the park and danced"

Your answer totally answered my question, but I phrased it wrong. Going to edit original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this using the indexOf() method available to strings. This returns the character location of the first occurrence of whatever you're looking for. Then use substring

```
var i = foo.indexOf('#');
foo = foo.substr(0,i);
```